# "SSO" between Intune Company Portal app and 3rd party iOS app

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, mdm, azure-ad-msal, intune

Is it possible to have my 3rd party iOS app use a shared token from the Intune Company Portal app to bypass authentication? I'm able to do this between two 3rd party apps by logging into one of them, and having the other one fetch token silently from iOS keychain. I'm using the [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) framework for authenticating with Azure AD.

The apps are living on an MDM managed (Intune) iOS device running iOS 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up an [issue on the MSAL GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/525) asking about this. It turns out it's only possible to have keychain sharing between your own apps. This is a restriction set by Apple:

> Xcode automatically prefixes keychain groups with your team ID. This
>   ensures that your groups are specific to your development team.

Taken from the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into MS Authenticator app to be used as cross-app SSO broker? As of my understanding Company Portal app acts as broker only for Android. Also Authenticator seems to support only ADAL and not MSAL so far.

[Howto enable SSO for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v1-enable-sso-ios)

Comment: Yes, I did check out the ADAL lib, but in this particular case I had to use the MSAL lib, which is the newer of the two.